# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json error

Tags: powershell-3.0

I created one simple PowerShell script **fromJson.ps1** (below):

```
param([string]$Jstring, [string]$JColumn)
$val = $Jstring | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json | select $Jcolumn
$val | format-table -auto
```

Now I am trying to parse some sample JSON using below method but it fails with an "Invalid JSON primitive" error. I am running it directly from a command prompt and calling **powershell.exe**.

```
c:\powershell>PowerShell.exe ./FromJson.ps1 '{"username":"","uid":"","contextid":8651,"partnerEntID":0}' "contextid"
```

Error :

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: . At
C:\SCRIPTS\PowerShell\FromJson.ps1:2 char:32
+ $val = $Jstring | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json | select $Jcolumn
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Though same works absolutely fine if I run it on powershell prompt.

```
PS C:\PowerShell> ./FromJson.ps1 '{"username":"","uid":"","contextid":8651,"partnerEntID":0}' "contextid"
```

Has someone run into this issue and resolve it ?
Thanks,
NJ

Answer (score 0):

The cmd parser handles quotes differently than the PowerShell parser.  Use the following to get the same results in cmd.

```
powershell "& {./FromJson.ps1 '{\"username\":\"\",\"uid\":\"\",\"contextid\":8651,\"partnerEntID\":0}' \"contextid\"}"
```

Steve